# iframe and frameset issue

Tags: html, iframe, web, frameset

I am using a free domain provider(freenom.com)
They provide us a url forwarding feature free of cost.
We can set our main website in iframe there.

My main website is : www.maleenes.com/shop/
&
Free domain website is: fashionary.ga
where main website is dispalyed in iframe.

My problem is that when you click on any link in iframe website then
I want it to change the url and navigate to the original website .
just like below reference website:

For example.
The Iframe is on dresswego.ga.
As soon as you click on something the url changes to original website wegodress.com

i want the same for my website fashionary.ga & www.maleenes.com/shop

Can anyone help me please/

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to change the browser url or iframe url?

Comment: i want to change the browser url. Can you please help me how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Web browsers does not allow to change the top most parent URL of page from cross domain Iframe.